# Update only if the new value is not Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I've written an stored procedure which updates the fields based on the values passed in parameters.

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE T1 
( 
@a INTEGER,  
@b INTEGER,    
@c nvarchar(max), 
@d nvarchar(max)
)  
AS  
BEGIN 
UPDATE Feed
Set b=@b,
    c=ISNULL(@c,c), 
    d=ISNULL(@d,d),     
where a = @a    
end
```

Now it is very common that we may need to update only some of the fields at a time. Suppose I only want to update `c`. Now in this case, parameters `b` & `d` should be `Null`. Hence, I am handling that with `IsNull()`.

But, the thing is that `@b` is an `int` and hence it's passing as `0` instead of `Null`. How to handle this update.

If the value passed is `0` then that column should not be updated.

**Note:** There won't be any case where my `int` columns will actually be `0`.

Comment: That procedure doesn't accept  *`NULL`* values. How are you passing a *`NULL`* for the parameters? An int can have an value of *`NULL`* . For example try: `DECLARE @i int; SELECT @i; SET @i = 1; SET @i = NULL; SELECT @i;` notice that *`NULL`*  is returned in both statements.

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done via CASE within UPDATE:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE T1 
    ( 
    @a INTEGER,  
    @b INTEGER,    
    @c nvarchar(max), 
    @d nvarchar(max)
    )  
    AS  
    BEGIN 
    UPDATE Feed
    Set b=case when @b = 0 then b else @b end,
        c=ISNULL(@c,c), 
        d=ISNULL(@d,d),     
    where a = @a    
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

As said the previous comment you can use `CASE WHEN...` but I prefer use `IIF(@b = 0, b, @b)` to be more clean

```
CREATE PROCEDURE T1(
    @a INTEGER,
    @b INTEGER,
    @c nvarchar(max),
    @d nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Feed
    Set b= IIF(@b = 0, b, @b),
        c=ISNULL(@c, c),
        d=ISNULL(@d, d)
    WHERE a = @a
end
```

the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax